# Azure blob storage is giving "request was aborted" for almost all my PUT requests

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to use Azure blob storage to store blobs, but the majority of the time I get "request was aborted" responses back from the blob store. I'm using the Node.js v10 SDK in an Express API, and I get the feeling that it has to do with how I'm configuring the service.

I'm using Azurite to mimic the Azure storage service.

In my app.js I run my function `configureBlobStore()` on startup:

```
export const configureBlobStore = async containerName => {
  const sharedKeyCredential = new SharedKeyCredential(
    process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
    process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY,
  );
  const pipeline = StorageURL.newPipeline(sharedKeyCredential);
  serviceUrl = new ServiceURL('http://blob:10000/devstoreaccount1', pipeline);

  if (!containerUrl) {
    containerUrl = ContainerURL.fromServiceURL(serviceUrl, containerName);
    try {
      await containerUrl.create(aborter);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log('Container already existed, skipping creation');
    }
  }
  return containerUrl;
};
```

and then to save blobs I run my function `saveToBlobStore()`

```
  let { originalname: blobName } = file;
  const blockBlobUrl = BlockBlobURL.fromContainerURL(containerUrl, blobName);
  const uploadOptions = { bufferSize: 4 * 1024 * 1024, maxBuffers: 20 };
  const stream = intoStream(file.buffer);

  try {
    await uploadStreamToBlockBlob(
      aborter,
      stream,
      blockBlobUrl,
      uploadOptions.bufferSize,
      uploadOptions.maxBuffers,
    );

    return blockBlobUrl.url;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error saving blob', err);
    return err;
  }
};
```

Sometimes it works, often when I take my containers down and do a volume prune, but usually it only works for the first file uploaded and not any others. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found the problem, I created an `Aborter` once, cached it and was using it for all of my calls, but you need to create a new one before each call to the blob store.

Comment: Kudos for replying your own question my friend.